# Rude/abusive flag not shown in Flag History

Tags: support, comment-flags, flag-history, rude-or-abusive

I recently raised a (subsequently accepted) comment flag for "Harrassment, bigotry, or abuse":

[image]

Nevertheless, my flag history shows only one "rude/abusive" flag:

[image]

which is an older (disputed) one:

[image]

Is this a bug, i.e. shouldn't the first flag above also be shown in my flag history under the "rude/abusive" filter, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rude/abusive flags only cover flags on posts, not comment flags. Comment flags can be found in the "comment flags" section.

Your first shown flag is not a "rude or abusive" one but a "It contains harassment, bigotry, or abuse." flag. Although they sound similar, these flags are actually different.

Comment: You are right, thanks. I thought that the shown flag was also for a comment, but revisiting the revision history showed that this was not the case, and the flag was raised for the post itself indeed.